# Substracting javascript times

Tags: javascript, date, time, subtraction

I'm having trouble with substracting times in javascript even though I've been googling for 2 days without any luck :(

I'm trying to time a questionnaire. 
When the user starts the questionnaire a timestamp is logged.
When the user finishes/clicks submit a new timestamp is logged, and the two times are subtracted to find out how much time the user spent.

(For this example I've just been using buttons...)
When i subtract i get NaN - Do I need to parse the miliseconds?

Code here: [Click](http://jsbin.com/pajogijemu/edit?js,output)

And Here:

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
 function myTimer(){
  var d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
 }

 function maal1(){
  var tid = new Date();
  document.getElementById("demoo").innerHTML = tid.getTime();
}

 function maal2(){
  var tid = new Date();
  document.getElementById("demooo").innerHTML = tid.getTime();
}

 function calc(){
  var tid1 = document.getElementById("demoo").value;
  var tid2 = document.getElementById("demooo").value;
  var tid3 = tid2 - tid1;
  document.getElementById("tident").innerHTML = tid3;
}
```

```html
<p class="centercenter" id="demo">Henter...</p></br>

<button class="centercenter" onClick="maal1()">Tid 1</button></br>

<p class="centercenter" id="demoo"></p></br>

<button class="centercenter" onClick="maal2()">Tid 2</button></br>

<p class="centercenter" id="demooo"></p></br>

<button class="centercenter" onClick="calc()">Calc</button></br>

<p class="centercenter" id="tident">Calc here</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function calc(){
        var tid1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("demoo").innerHTML) || 0;
        var tid2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("demooo").innerHTML) || 0;

        var tid3 = tid2 - tid1;
        document.getElementById("tident").innerHTML = tid3;
}
```

Your innerHTML is fine, but it's taken as a string. String minus string = NaN (Not a number)

Parse to int (or parseFloat for decimals) and it should work.

(Incidentally, i've added || 0 incase of null strings, edge case I know, but non-breaking)

Comment: Excellent! Many good answers - I like this for simplicity :) Thanks man!

Comment: No probs. Have fun! :)

Comment: "*String minus string = NaN*" nope. The minus operator coerces its operands to number, so as long as the string converts to a number (which the result of *getTime* does), there is no need for parseInt. The real issue is with `var tid1 = document.getElementById("demoo").value;`, which should use `.innerHTML` or `.textContent` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tid1 = document.getElementById("demoo").value;
var tid2 = document.getElementById("demooo").value;
```

should be

```
var tid1 = document.getElementById("demoo").innerHTML;
var tid2 = document.getElementById("demooo").innerHTML;
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

First, `value` will get you `undefined` as this is not an input. You need to get the text value from `p` using the `innerText` property.

You are essentially subtracting the string values you get from `getElementById(...).innerText`.
You need to use the `Date` object, so you need to convert the string value to a number and then pass it to `Date` constructor, something like the following:

```
var tid1 = new Date(parseInt(document.getElementById("demoo").innerText));
var tid2 = new Date(parseInt(document.getElementById("demooo").innerText));
var tid3 = tid2 - tid1;
```

---

***A side note on parseInt method***

Be careful though with the `parseInt()` method use. This method will take only the rightmost numbers it finds in an expression, even if it is not a valid number as a whole, for example:

```
var x = "5 Answers";
console.log(parseInt(x)); // Prints "5"
```

Better use the `Number` constructor to safely convert to number, if your inputs may contain non-numeric characters:

```
var x = "5 Asnwers";
var num = Number(x);
console.log(num); // Prints NaN
```

Comment: There is no need to create a Date object, the result is identical to `document.getElementById("demoo").textContent - document.getElementById("demooo").textContent`. *innerText* is a non–standard property that is not supported in all browsers in use. Use *innerHTML* or *textContent* instead.

Comment: @RobG yes I am aware regarding innerText, it is not W3C standard, but it works for latest versions just fine. There is support from Firefox 45+.
But I couldn't agree more, that `innerText` should not be used, `innerHTML` is a better option. `textContent` has issues with IE.
http://caniuse.com/#search=innerText

Regarding the `Date`, I've added it just for verbosity in order to help the op. No impact on performance from creating two new objects. There is no educational value in subtracting just the textContent and present this as answer, especially to a beginner.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use an external library as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in order to help you achieve that

Comment: I checked it out, but it seems a bit much for such a simple task. Looks cool though!